# How is $\bigcup \{a,b,c,d\}$ defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have the set $A=\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$. We know that $\bigcup A=\{a,b,c,d\}$. However, say we have $B=\{a,b,c,d\}$. How is $\bigcup B$ defined?

Comment: "We know that $\cup A = \{a,b,c,d\}$": How do we know this? It's not notation I'm familiar with, at least.

Comment: This reads really strange. I have a feeling you are misunderstanding because $\bigcup A = A$ unless you are using some alternative usage of $\bigcup$ than standard... Union is the collection of all of the elements in the individual sets you are putting together. Here, $A$ has only two elements: the two-element sets $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$. While these sets themselves have elements, the objects in $A$ are just the sets. It was never said that elements of sets had to be numbers; they can be anything (to a point!). In this case, the elements are also sets.

Comment: @user: This is a standard notation, at least in some contexts. It means the same thing as $\bigcup_{s\in A} s$.

Answer (score 1):

$\bigcup B = a \cup b \cup c \cup d$, the set of all things that are an element of $a$, $b$, $c$, or $d$.

It is, of course, meaningless notation if $a$, $b$, $c$, or $d$ is a variable that represents a type of object for which it is meaningless to talk about things being an element of it.